# How can I submit Create but not Redirect to Action (ASP.NET MVC 5)

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

My View Edit have some steps and I would like to Save step by step, I think I need a JQuery for it, don't know how.

Steps:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">                            
    <li class="active">
        <a href="#cliente" data-toggle="tab">Cliente</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#peca" data-toggle="tab">Peças</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#validacao" data-toggle="tab">Validação</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#instalacao" data-toggle="tab">Instalação</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#colaboradores" data-toggle="tab">Colaboradores</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Submit Button:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
        <input type="hidden" value="Save" id="salvar" class="btn btn-default" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Post Controller:

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
    db.Entry(manutencao).State = EntityState.Modified;
    db.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Index");

}
```

Comment: If you want to save step by step, you should use ajax to save, after each tab.

Comment: It's hard to tell from your question, but it sounds like you want to do incremental saves without reloading the page.  You need to look at AJAX form submitting to do this.

Comment: Or, use 5 different pages posting to the server

Comment: Try to  user knokout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the commenters mentioned, to prevent a page refresh, you need to do an ajax request.  [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) is certainly a good option, but you could use native javascript as well.

Something like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'controller action url',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
       whatever
    },
    success: function (results) {
         do stuff
    }
});
```